# Аналог $(this) на нативном js

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть код который получает заданное сss свойство

```
$('.block').click(function() {
console.log($(this).css('color'))
})
```

как получить его на нативной js ?

такой код не работает

```
$('.block').click(function() {
console.log(this.css('color'))
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Тут подробнее (справочник Мозиллы)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Ну и до кучи - [как обходиться без jq](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```
getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue("color")
```